# Why is my player movement inverted when I turn around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used rigidbodies a lot and recently started using character controllers. I have basic movement code for my character controller here:

```
public void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;
if (isGrounded)
        {
            x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        }
        Vector3 move = Vector3.forward * z + Vector3.right * x;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (!isGrounded)
        {
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime; // Gravity for jumps

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

The reason I am using this code is because I'm trying to make sure that when my player jumps, the jump **does not** follow my camera around. This code does that, however if I rotate 180 degrees on the y axis, my WASD keys all become inverted. I've tried adding * (1) but that just makes it worse. If I replace Vector3.forward & Vector3.right to transform.forward & transform.right, the keys are no longer inverted but then my jump is controlled by my mouse movement, so I'm really trying to get the first line of code to work.

Comment: You should read [ask] and then [mcve] and then try to improve the question. There is very little for us to go on at the moment.

Comment: I've made some edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vector3.forward` is always (1, 0, 0). If you want the movement to be based on the camera's rotation you need to use `Transform.forward` and `Transform.right`(Assuming your character only has rotation around the y axis)

If you don't want the jump to be controllable mid-air, you have to logic to create momentum and prevent the player from changing their momentum if they are in the air. The first line is never going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have code to prevent WASD/jump movement while in the air (!isGrounded check). My issue is that my mouse basically controls my jump which is why I tried to stick with the Vector3 since it no longer was

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "my mouse controls my jump". I'm starting to think we're talking about different things.

Comment: Sorry, so basically if I walk or run and then jump simultaneously, I can control my jump mid-air by moving my mouse around which is not good. So essentially, I am able to spin around in circles mid air just by mouse rotation until my player lands. However with my Vector3 code above (which I now know is wrong), it prevents mouse rotation while mid-air which is good.

Comment: Create 2 variables, `Vector2 momentum` and `bool isInAir`. When the player jumps, set `isInAir` to true and `momentum` to the x and z velocity of the player. If `isInAir` is true, use `momentum` as the x and z movement, Otherwise, use the normal ground movement. When the player touches the ground, set `isInAir` to false

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I changed my Vector3.forward, etc, to transform.forward & right and also implemented that code. I got my momentum Vector2 with 2 values (velocity.x and velocity.z) and then the if (isInAir) for the momentum. I have no errors and everything runs fine, but I can still control my jump via moving my mouse. Maybe I missed something but everything looks fine. I also referred to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-velocity.html just incase, but still can't pin point it.

Comment: Can you post your code on github?(or somewhere else I can see it)

Comment: Yeah I have my movement: https://pastebin.com/RHgkVUKk and mouse: https://pastebin.com/nwzMevdS. I tried some more editing but that's basically what I've ended up on. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250973/discussion-between-aspectofthenoob-and-thehelaeper67).

Comment: Cheers a lot for all the help and all the comments you provided as well plus time spent fixing up my code. I appreciate it and it solved my problem.